# Unable to clone repository in docker-compose

Tags: git, docker, go, docker-compose

I'm trying to configure an app to run on localstack using docker-compose. I'm getting an error when attempting to clone the resository.

```
setup-resources_1  | make[1]: [/app/ProjectRecipes.mk:35: clean] Error 2 (ignored)
setup-resources_1  | ServiceName=Tests make -C /app/ -f /app/ProjectRecipes.mk deploy
setup-resources_1  | git clone https://github.com/MyGithOrg/TestProject /Users/antarr.byrd/go/src/github.com/MyGithOrg/TestProject
setup-resources_1  | Cloning into '/Users/antarr.byrd/go/src/github.com/MyGithOrg/TestProject'...
localstack_1       | Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
setup-resources_1  | fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
setup-resources_1  | make[4]: *** [/app/ProjectRecipes.mk:24: /Users/antarr.byrd/go/src/github.com/MyGithOrg/TestProject] Error 128
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "53:53"
      - "443:443"
      - "4510-4520:4510-4520"
      - "4566-4620:4566-4620"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - LOCALSTACK_API_KEY=${LOCALSTACK_API_KEY}
      - SERVICES=serverless,rds,lambda,sqs,dynamodb,s3,apigateway,stepfunctions,cloudformation,appsync,firehose,es
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR}
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    networks:
      - default

  setup-resources:
    image: golang:1.16.4-alpine3.13
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c
    working_dir: /app
    command: >
      "
        ls
        apk add --update alpine-sdk
        make Tests
      "
    networks:
      - default
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ~/go
        target: /go
      - type: bind
        source: ${HOME}
        target: /root
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /app
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
      - ~/.gitconfig:/root/.gitconfig
    depends_on:
      - localstack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem:

The following command fails in your container because it is an interactive command that expects the user to enter `username` and `password` for GitHub. Although this is not the case in your local machine, that is the case inside the container. I don't know the reason for the difference .

```sh
git clone https://github.com/MyGithOrg/TestProject /Users/antarr.byrd/go/src/github.com/MyGithOrg/TestProject
```

---

### Solution:

You can clone your repository through SSH using the following command:

```sh
git clone ssh://git@github.com/MyGithOrg/TestProject.git /Users/antarr.byrd/go/src/github.com/MyGithOrg/TestProject
```

---

### Steps:

1. Update your clone command to use SSH like above.
2. If you haven't configured an SSH key in your Github profile, you can follow [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) to do so.

   > ​⚠️​ Make sure at this step you are able to clone the repo using SSH in your local machine.
3. Update your `command` in docker-compose file to install an SSH client

   ```sh
   command: >
     "
       ls
       apk add --update alpine-sdk openssh
       make Tests
     "
   ```
4. If you're using a Mac, then make sure you have `IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain` above `UseKeychain yes` in your `~/.ssh/config` file.

   > ℹ️ The reason is that `openssh` version that is being installed in your Golang Alpine image does not recognize `UseKeychain` option and will throw you `Bad configuration option: usekeychain` error. You can read more about that in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2449/_index.html).

   Example of a correct `~/.ssh/config` file:

   ```sh
   Host *
     AddKeysToAgent yes
     IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
     UseKeychain yes
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```
5. Then update your `volumes` like below:

   ```sh
   volumes:
     - type: bind
       source: ~/go
       target: /go
     - type: bind
       source: .
       target: /app
     - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
   ```

   Note that you no longer need `~/.gitconfig:/root/.gitconfig` volume. I also removed your mapping of `HOME` directory to `/root` of the container because I still doubt that it might cause issues.

I believe this should work for you now. Cheers  !!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `signingkey`. Would that be `~/.ssh/id_rsa` ?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, that’s not really necessary. It is used when you want to sign the commit and verify that you’re the one who actually made that commit. So other than that, did you find the other properties in your gitconfig? What was the directory of your gitconfig?

Comment: Yes, its in `~/.gitconfig`

Comment: If you run `git clone https://github.com/MyGithOrg/TestProject /Users/antarr.byrd/go/src/github.com/MyGithOrg/TestProject` in your local machine, does it clone your project without asking for your github username or github password?

Comment: If that is also working, my next guess is that this issue is coming because you mount your HOME directory to root directory of your docker. Could you instead mount the specific sub directories you want (like you mounted `go` directory) or just remove it.

Comment: Were you able to find the issue?

Comment: I was able to map it directly. But still not able to clone the repository if it is not on my machine

Comment: You mean you can clone from your local, but when you use docker-compose you still get the same error? Or now your docker-compose works, but it does not work from someone else’s machine?

Comment: It works on the host but not in docker-compose

Comment: Did you try removing your volume type: bind
        source: ${HOME}
        target: /root?

Comment: yeah, didn't help

Comment: I wrote my answer from the scratch. I tested this on my machine and I believe this would work for you as well.

Comment: The problem was git and ssh was missing on the machine but it wasn't throwing any errors to point to that. Thanks for you help

Comment: I’m afraid I didn’t follow. When you say git and ssh was missing on the machine, did you mean that you haven’t had a SSH key to access GitHub in your local machine? How did you resolve the issue?

Comment: The actual packages `git` and `openssh` needed to be installed using `apk`